# My html/js map is compiling on some places properly, but is displaying a blank white screen when I try to put it onto a web server

Tags: javascript, html, webserver, openlayers

I'm currently having issues with an html file working on web servers, as all of the other files display on the web server properly except for the html map itself.

I've made sure that the web-server I'm using (Fenix) can run other html files, and it can.  However, when I add in my index.html (my map), the whole entire web-server displays a white screen.  I've attached screenshots below showing the issue along with my index.html code, any help is greatly appreciated!

Without index.html
[image]

With index.html
[image]

index.html code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Map Skeleton</title>
    <style>
      .map {
        width: 100%;
        height: 400px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Additionally, here is the js code in case it is needed.

```
import Map from "ol/Map";
import View from "ol/View";
import TileLayer from "ol/layer/Tile";
import OSM from "ol/source/OSM";

var map = new Map({
  layers: [
    new TileLayer({
      source: new OSM()
    })
  ],
  target: "map",
  view: new View({
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 2
  })
});
```

Along with the package.json file

```
{
  "name": "Map Skeleton",
  "dependencies": {
    "ol": "6.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "parcel": "1.11.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "parcel index.html",
    "build": "parcel build --experimental-scope-hoisting --public-url . index.html"
  }
}
```

Any help is appreciated, and I'm sorry if this is a simple solution. Thank you!

Comment: any errors in the javascript console?

Comment: have you "compiled" it (`npm start`)? The content served by you server is strange. It looks like your entire project, while it should only be the `dist` or `wwwroot` folder. At last, don't forget to include the ol css! Check this [doc](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/doc/tutorials/bundle.html)

Comment: @JGH I feel like SUCH an idiot, compiled it and it worked.  Thank you so much haha.